# How access methods of another classes?

Tags: vb.net

I'm with troubles for access methods of another class "SocketClient" in a "Form2", but in "Form1" works very fine! In other words, I can send data from "Form1" using methods of "SocketClient", but the same thing I don't can do from "Form2".

How solve it?

Here is my code:

**"Form1"**

```
Public Class Form1

Public WithEvents C As New SocketClient
Public Yy As String = "|SPLIT|"

 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

  C.Send("ref" & Yy & "data here")

End Sub
End Class
```

**"Form2"**

```
 Public Class Form2 

    Public frm1 As Form1

     Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click

     ' The error is here, don't sends data to server application
      frm1.C.Send("ref" & frm1.Yy & "Name: " & TextBox1.Text)

    End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: What's the problem?  I am guessing that `frm1` is null, since you don't show any code where it's initialized, but you should include any error details and the line it occurs in your question.

Comment: @Mark, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have Form1 as the main form and you are creating Form2 from that main form, try passing a reference via the constructor:

```
Public Class Form2
  Private frm1 As Form1

  Public Sub New(mainForm As Form1)
    Me.InitializeComponent()
    frm1 = mainForm
  End Sub

End Class
```

From your main form (form1), you would pass the reference:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click  
  Dim form2 As New Form2(Me)
  form2.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: With  base on code above (or any other), how stays this Form2 accessing a variable or method in Form1?

Comment: @JonasSilva Because you are passing a reference of Form1 to Form2 and storing that reference in the frm1 variable.  If I understood your comment.  Try it.